# Is there a callback for when a task is completed in Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

Suppose I have the following:

```
IEnumerable<Task<TimeSpan>> tasks = //...
TimeSpan[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
// Handle results
```

By the time I can handle the results all the task must have finished.

Is there a way to handle each result *on demand*?

Like registering a delegate / callback that will get executed when a task is completed:

```
IEnumerable<Task<TimeSpan>> tasks = //...
await Task.WhenAll(tasks, result =>
{
   // A task has finished. This will get executed.
   // result is of type TimeSpan
});
```

Comment: Maybe `tasks[i].ContinueWith()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to handle each result on demand?

Yes, you use `WhenAny` instead of `WhenAll`... or call `ContinueWith` on each task.

For example, for the `WhenAny` approach:

```
ISet<Task<TimeSpan>> tasks = new HashSet<Task<TimeSpan>>(...);
while (tasks.Count != 0)
{
    var task = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
    // Use task here
    tasks.Remove(task);
}
```

There's another option you could use, where you transform the original sequence of tasks into a sequence of tasks which completes in order, but giving the same results. Details are in [this blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/01/16/eduasync-part-19-ordering-by-completion-ahead-of-time/), but the result is that you can use:

```
foreach (var task in tasks.InCompletionOrder())
{
    var result = await task;
    // Use the result
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm going to go with the `ContinueWith` approach, as it seems cleaner and more semantically correct

Comment: @MatiasCicero: Both are semantically correct - it just depends on what ends up being simplest. Adding a link to another alternative...

Comment: @AbdelrhmanMohamed: Because we're only calling `WhenAny` - we need as many iterations as there are tasks...

Comment: @AbdelrhmanMohamed: Although now that plast1k has edited my post, I see that it was very confusing before - sorry about that!

Answer (score 12):

> Is there a way to handle each result on demand?
>
> Like registering a delegate / callback that will get executed when a task is completed

Yes, you just have to adjust your thinking a bit.

Forget registering callbacks ([`ContinueWith` is a dangerous, extremely low-level API](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html)). Also, you almost never have to order tasks by completion. Instead, think about your problem in terms of *operations* (tasks).

Right now, you have a collection of tasks that return `TimeSpan`. Each item in that collection is a single operation that returns `TimeSpan`. What you really want to do is introduce the concept of a single higher-level operation that waits for the original operation to complete and then executes your post-operation logic.

This is exactly what `async`/`await` is for:

```
private static async Task<TimeSpan> HandleResultAsync(Task<TimeSpan> operation)
{
  var result = await operation;
  // A task has finished. This will get executed.
  // result is of type TimeSpan
  ...
  return result; // (assuming you want to propagate the result)
}
```

Now, you want to apply this higher-level operation to your existing operations. LINQ's `Select` is perfect for this:

```
IEnumerable<Task<TimeSpan>> tasks = ...
IEnumerable<Task<TimeSpan>> higherLevelTasks = tasks.Select(HandleResultAsync);

TimeSpan[] results = await Task.WhenAll(higherLevelTasks);
// By the time you get here, all results have been handled individually.
```

If you don't need the final collection of results, this can be further simplified:

```
private static async Task HandleResultAsync(Task<TimeSpan> operation)
{
  var result = await operation;
  // A task has finished. This will get executed.
  // result is of type TimeSpan
  ...
}

IEnumerable<Task<TimeSpan>> tasks = ...
IEnumerable<Task> higherLevelTasks = tasks.Select(HandleResultAsync);
await Task.WhenAll(higherLevelTasks);
```

Comment: I'm really *amazed* by your usage of LINQ's `Select`. It's just perfect!